# Reference of the ergodic theorem in continuous time

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space and $\tau_t:\Omega\to\Omega$ for $t\ge0$ such that

1. $\tau_0=\operatorname{id}_\Omega$
2. $\tau_{s+t}=\tau_s\tau_t$ for all $s,t\ge0$
3. $\tau:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\to\Omega$ is $\left(\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B\left([0,\infty)\right),\mathcal A\right)$-measurable
4. $\operatorname P\circ\:\tau_t^{-1}=\operatorname P$ for all $t\ge0$

Now, let $$\mathcal I:=\left\{A\in\mathcal A:\tau_t^{-1}(A)=A\text{ for all }t\ge0\right\}.$$

> I'm searching for a reference (with proof) of the ergodic theorem of the following form: If $p\in[1,\infty)$ and $F\in\mathcal L^1(\operatorname P)$, then $$\frac1t\int_0^tF\circ\tau_t\:{\rm d}t\xrightarrow{t\to\infty}\operatorname E\left[F\mid\mathcal I\right]\tag1$$ almost surely and in $L^p(\operatorname P)$. I was only able to find either the discrete-time analogue or the special where $\tau$ is the time-shift on the canonical probability space of a stochastic process.

Comment: I have a proof in  my notes on ergodic theory. You can go to statmathbc.wordpress.com and locate the notes in Ergodic Theory  by opening the catalog.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your comment. (a) Unfortunately, I need a reference to a "widely accepted" book. Do you know one? (b) Is there an continuous-time analogue of [Theorem 3.18 here](http://wt.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/WT/Inhalt/people/Andreas_Eberle/Markov_Processes_1617/MPSkript1617.pdf)?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh, and why does that theorem hold at all? In the proof, the author is reducing the problem to the case where the chain is started in stationarity, but in order for $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nf(X_i)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\int f\:{\rm d}\mu$ to hold (in the stationary case) we need ergodicity ... What am I missing?

Comment: Ergodicity is need if you insist that the limit is a constant. Without ergodicity the limit still exists a.s. and the limit is the conditional expectation you have mentioned in your question. Ergodic Theorem is valid for all measure preserving transformations.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, I know. That's what I mean. In Theorem 3.18 the author is claiming that $A_{b,\:n}f\to\int f\:{\rm d}\mu$ (if the total variation $|\mu-\nu\pi^n|$ tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$). But it seems like he's not assuming that $\nu\pi$ is ergodic wrt the shift $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\to(x_{n+1})_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes late for @0xbadf00d but for others: a cts. time version of Birkhoff's Ergodic Theorem with proof can be found in Olav Kallenberg's Foundation of Modern Probability Volume 2 (3rd edition), p. 563.